# Sass compiler on Sublime Text 3

Tags: sass, sublimetext3

Is there available any sass compiler for Sublime Text 3? I've searched everywhere but I just found only compiler plugins for Sublime Text 2. I've also used Koala to compile .scss to .css but it doesn't work with Live Reload plugin so it's pointless. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

install SublimeOnSaveBulid and sass build